# Htaccess Rewrite for Multiple Optional Parameters

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So essentially want I'm working on is Guild Hosting site but my htaccess isn't working anymore, here is what I want:

```
http://www.example.com/?page=test => http://www.example.com/test

http://www.example.com/?site=testsite => http://testsite.example.com or http://www.testsite.example.com
http://www.example.com/?site=testsite&page=test => http://testsite.example.com/test or http://www.testsite.example.com/test
```

I'm going to make it so PHP processes whether or not the site has a WWW. or not at the start of the web address using a boolean set in a MySQL Database but for now I just want to know how can setup my `.htaccess` file to display all the sites like this and possibly redirect them to the right ones? Here is my current `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.dev.randamonium.com$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /index.php?site=%1&site=%2 [L]

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

Options All -Indexes
```

I've tried looking for different things similar to this but I can't find ones specifically like mine so any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was looking at different examples and messing around with the `.htaccess` and ended up making it work!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.dev.randamonium.com$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?site=%1&page=$2 [L]

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

Options All -Indexes
```

So if anyone else is working on a similar project just use this code and it will work but you just need to use PHP to process all the pages and subdomains, etc.